# Looking for a way to trigger a function when a value is switched from 0 to 1 in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, onchange

I am trying to integrate some motion sensor gadgets with some software.In order to get it the way I want, I need my program to activate a script when a motion sensor changes its sensor value from a 0 (no movement) to a 1 (movement detected). I have been going in circles for quite sometime as I have been trying to learn HTML, JavaScript, and CSS for a couple months.

Here is the code I am stuck at.

```
<tr>
<td><input readonly type='text' style="font-size: xx-large;" id='sensorValue' value="0"><label id='unit' >V/V</label></td>
</tr>
```

The closest I have got was having it activate the script when i manually enter some type of input myself but never could get it to do it on its own.

Any help is appreciated. I am so close to completing this phase of the project and this is the last thing holding me up.

I have tried using many different onchange type of events ranging from onblur, onchange, and oninput. I even made a button to verify that my script i made to communicate with the software works (Which it did.). I expected that when I entered `onchange="myfunction()"` in the input line it would activate the function every time the JavaScript changed the sensor reading on it's own, but it didn't.

Comment: Is the value of the input changed programmatically? Can't you just trigger your function there?

Comment: So what is actually setting the value? My guess is you are attacking this at the wrong place in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the value programmatically, there's no `change` event triggered. However, you can create this event yourself and just dispatch it on the element. See below:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const trigger = () => { console.log("I updated"); }

(function() {
  input.value = "luigi";
  input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));
})()
```

```html
<input readonly id="input" type="text" value="mario" onchange="trigger();"/>
```